# Is it possible to access the current route component with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

For example I have routes like:

```
<Route path="about" component={AboutPage} />
<Route path="status" component={StatusPage} />
```

Lets assume that the current route is `'#/about'`. I need something like `routerInstance.currentComponent` to return `AboutPage` component instance.

Does React Router has a method to do it?

ps. I understand that accessing component instances from the outside is not the React Way to do things, but nevertheless I need it.

Answer (score 2):

not sure if react-router already exposes it, theres an old GitHub discussing undocumented api's, [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1125) but you could set it yourself per Route.

```
//AboutPage
componentDidMount() {
  global.currentComponent  = this
}

//StatusPage
componentDidMount() {
  global.currentComponent  = this
}
```

Comment: sure, that's exactly what I'm doing now, but I was hoping for some built-in approach.

Comment: just looked through the router component source and it doesn't look like it exposes what you need

Comment: Take a look at this github [issue](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1125) for exposed api's